# Stack Overflow - No. of votes are not represented in "kvotes", just like "kviews"

Tags: bug, user-interface, score

I queried for a keyword (core java) and clicked 'votes' tab to see the Q/A with the highest no. of votes. There, I can see a Answer with 10581 no.of Votes with last digit(1) aligned outside of colored box.

It will be good to see, if the no. of votes (exceeding 1000) were represented in "**kvotes**", just like "**kviews**". :) [since initially the number(10581) shown me like 1058 votes and below post with 4076 votes & confused why the posts were not sorted in descending.]

*See the below screenshot taken:*

[image: Highest voted posts containing core java Stack Overflow]

Comment: Normally, they are. Search is different.

Comment: @michaelb958 No, you are wrong. You are mixing votes with views.

Comment: @MIH ...so I am. The frontpage *does* use `kvotes`, and I got confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very rare to have a question or answer that makes it to 1,000 votes, hence it is something to show as is! like a little show off ;)

**Little stats**: out of **6.6 million** questions on SO (??? million answers), there are **[only 243 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A1000)** (questions + answers) that have 1,000 votes or more, while there are [1.2 million questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A1000) that have more than 1,000 views.